# Explicit solution of SDE with linear drift and constant diffusion

Tags: reference-request, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let

- $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$ be a probability space
- $(B_t)_{t\ge0}$ be a Brownian motion on $(\Omega,\mathcal A,\operatorname P)$
- $b:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ be linear
- $\sigma>0$

We know that the SDE $${\rm d}X_t=b(X_t)\:{\rm d}t+\sigma{\rm d}W_t$$ has a unique strong solution. Are we able to express this solution explicitly [as it's the case for $b(x)=x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1317019/sde-solution-using-it%c3%b4-formula)?

Comment: If $b$ is linear then $b(x) = ax$ for some $a \in \mathbb{R}$. Consider $a^{-1}X_t$ (noting that the case $a = 0$ is trivial).

Comment: Any transformation $Y_t=F(t,X_t)$ leads per Ito theorem to
$$
dY_t=(F_t+F_xb(X_t)+\tfrac12F_{xx}σ^2)dt+F_xσdW_t.
$$
To be a sensible simplification, one might want the first term to be zero,
$$
0=F_t(t,x)+F_x(t,x)b(x)+\tfrac12F_{xx}(t,x)σ^2
$$
which in general is a non-trivial PDE.